# Changing background color of selected row in shiny data table not working

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app with a data table and I would like to change the default color for selected rows. I found various posts addressing this issue and suggesting to add a style tag

```
tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: #505050 !important;}'))
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for me. I'm sure there is a very simple solution that I'm just not seeing and I would really appreciate your advice.

Here is reproducible code for my table:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

tabledata1 <- cbind(c("Variable 1", "Variable 2", "Variable 3", "Variable 4",
                      "Variable 5"), c(10,20,30,40,50))
tabledata1

tabledata2 <- rbind(c("Heading 1",""), tabledata1[1,], 
                      c("Heading 2",""),tabledata1[2:3,],
                      c("Heading 3",""),tabledata1[4:5,])
tabledata2

headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css('display', 'none');",
  "}"
)

ui <- basicPage(
  
tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: #505050 !important;}')),

dataTableOutput('tab1')

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
my_vals <- tabledata2[,1]
my_bkgcolors <- ifelse(my_vals %in% c("Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3"), 
                       '#1D667F', '#e9eff1')
my_fontcolors <- ifelse(my_vals %in% c("Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3"), 
                        '#FFFFFF', '#000000')
my_fontweights <- ifelse(my_vals %in% c("Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3"),
                         'bold', 'normal')
output$tab1 <- renderDataTable({
  datatable(as.data.frame(tabledata2), 
            selection = list(mode = "single",
                             target = "row"),
            rownames=F, 
            options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = 20, 
                           scrollX = T, 
                           headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
            )) %>%
    formatStyle('V1', fontWeight = 'bold') %>% 
    formatStyle('V1', target = 'row',
                fontWeight = styleEqual(my_vals,my_fontweights)) %>%
    formatStyle('V1', target = 'row',
                backgroundColor = styleEqual(my_vals,my_bkgcolors)) %>%
    formatStyle('V1', target = 'row',
                color = styleEqual(my_vals,my_fontcolors)) 
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I ran your code as is and had no problem. I changed the value in "background-color: #505050"  and the background of the selected rows changed accordingly. What is it that you experienced when you ran the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v1.12 of DataTables, you need to use `box-shadow` instead of `background-color` to change row colours (see: https://datatables.net/blog/2022-05-13#Row-colouring-improvements, https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/209183/#Comment_209183 and https://www.w3schools.com/CSSREF/css3_pr_box-shadow.php).

In your code:

```
tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9999px #505050 !important;}')),
```